# Can I dual hit when stealthing to improve stealth damage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to hit using both weapons during a stealth attack, and still have a dual 15x bonus (assuming i have the backstabber perk)?

If yes, will the Assassination scene show when doing this?

Comment: I know the answer to the first part (yes you can), not sure if the assassination scene will show up though.

Comment: So i can hit with 2x Daggers and end up having 2x Hits with 15x Bonus ( or 30x with shrouded gloves ) ?

Comment: yes, it takes time for the NPC to 'respond' to a sneak attack, you can get in several such hits if you are fast enough before you are detected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can hit with both weapons and get the backstab bonus applied to both. Sometimes more than two swings, even, with a dual-wielding power attack.

No, the assassination scene won't show. It would have been cool, though.